# Download file with url redirection

Tags: bash, url, curl, download, wget

I can download a file by url but when I try it from bash I get a html page instead of a file.

How to download file with url redirection (301 Moved Permanently) using curl, wget or something else?

**UPD**

Headers from the url request.

> curl -I http://www.somesite.com/data/file/file.rar

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 07 Dec 2013 10:15:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3
Location: http://www.somesite.com/files/html/archive.html
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
X-Pad: avoid browser bug
```

Comment: `wget --content-disposition <URL>` , Could you try this?

Comment: Yes, I could. It doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: I get the same result with this option.

Comment: is this problem solved ?

Answer (score 105):

Use `-L, --location` to follow redirects:

```
$ curl -L http://httpbin.org/redirect/1
```

Comment: Get the content of the page from Location header. I've updated the question.

Comment: Hmm... but if you try to download a file (a binary archive here) and the `Location` header redirects you to a HTML file then the archive is no more available... I assume this HTML page contains an error message, isn't it? If not, does it include information (i.e. link) related to the original file you're trying to download? In such a case you would have to parse the HTML to extract it.

Comment: No, HTML page doesn't contain error info but it contain relative path to file: `<a href="_blank>/data/file/file.rar</a>` as I use with domain name to download the file but it doesn't work. I guess there is other domain name for its files but I don't know how to figure out it.

Comment: So you need to first resolve this issue, then parse and reconstruct the right link to follow this redirection.

Comment: Works for me. Example, I'm downloading the jenkins war file which redirects, I could do `curl -O -L http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.60.1/jenkins.war`